# Retrieve id element from html in C# code MVC .NET?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

Im working in a MVC .NET application. I assign a value to an element ID like this:

```
document.getElementById("latbox").value = event.latLng.lat();
```

and I retrieve it to show it like this:

```
<p>Latitud: <input size="20" type="text" id="latbox" name="lat" ></p>
```

The thing is, how can I find this value in my controller? Thanks.

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? Do you want to send the value of the 'latbox' input box to your controller? Or are you trying to set this value from your controller? You need to provide a more detailed use case

Comment: Sorry if I have explained wrong, I want to GET this value from my controller. Thanks.

Comment: You mean, you want to post this value to your controller?

Comment: Whatever I need to use the value in the controller, Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your view, you can use a `<input type='hidden' name='lat'/>` that you assign the value you need. Note that it must match the name of your controller parameter

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Action", "Controller", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        <p>Latitud: <input size="20" type="text" id="latbox" name="lat"></p>
        <input type="hidden" name="lat" id="latbox-hidden" />

        <input type="submit" value="submit" />
    }

    <script type="text/javascript">
      var lat = document.getElementById("latbox");
      lat.value = "foo";

      document.getElementById("latbox-hidden").value = lat.value;
      alert(document.getElementById("latbox-hidden").value);
    </script>
```

And your controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Action(string id, string lat) //same name to bind
    {
             //do your thing
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

HTML fields are posted using the name attribute, which in your case is "lat". On the controller you could have a parameter like this:

```
string lat
```

It would get the value of the HTML input element.

Comment: Sorry, I get it now, this is a return value of my ActionResult. THANKS, It got clarified with the other answer

Answer (score 1):

You can also use ajax call to send data to action

```
<head runat="server">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var serviceURL = '/AjaxTest/FirstAjax'; // give path of your action
        var param = document.getElementById("latbox");
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: serviceURL,
            data: param,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: successFunc,
            error: errorFunc
        });

        function successFunc(data, status) {     
            alert(data);
        }

        function errorFunc() {
            alert('error');
        }
    });
</script>
```